# Hide sheets from user by logged in email or author

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that has multiple authors, each of them should only be able to see their own worksheet and the primary sheet. I have a limited understanding of VBA from past coding but if hiding a sheet by either email they are logged into, by their outlook contact info, or the author is possible while still sharing the same file, I'd love the how-to.
I did a bit of research already and understand that I can get the username and check by that, but asking everyone for their PC username is rough.

Comment: Password protect each sheet for each author.

Comment: just as a comment Microsoft 365 online doesnt run VBA so if you share through that service you could possibly achieve this in the users desktop excel but not in 365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA can be easily hacked by somebody skilled... If people using the workbook in discussion are not so skilled and you intend protect the VBA project, you can try using a function able to return what you need. It will work only **if the user has Outlook installed and its default/primary user account is the one you know** and use in your code. Just for the sake of playing with VBA, try the next function:

```
Function getActiveOutlookAccount() As String
   Dim Outl As Object, OutMail As Object, boolAlreadyOp As Boolean
   
   On Error Resume Next
     Set Outl = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
   On Error GoTo 0
   If Outl Is Nothing Then
        Set Outl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Else
        boolAlreadyOp = True
   End If
   Set OutMail = Outl.CreateItem(0) 'necessary to expose Outlook namespace...
   getActiveOutlookAccount = Outl.GetNamespace("MAPI").CurrentUser.Address

   If Not boolAlreadyOp Then Outl.Quit: Set Outl = Nothing 'quit Outlook if not already open before running the code...
End Function
```

It can be tested using the next sub:

```
Sub getAccount()
  Dim currentAcc As String
   currentAcc = getActiveOutlookAccount
   Debug.Print currentAcc
   'use it to set access to specific worksheets...
End Sub
```